# The method parseInt() in the type integer is not applicable for the arguments (JTextField) in Action Listener (Java)

Tags: java, parsing

I have an `ActionListener` for a `JButton` (I am using WidgetViewer).
This is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.Actionlistener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Interface {
       public static void main(String[] args) {

       WidgetViewer wv = new WidgetViewer();
       
       JLabel eventName = new JLabel("Event Name");
       wv.add(eventName, 10, 30, 300, 20);
        
       JTextField name = new JTextField();
       wv.add(name, 10, 50, 300, 20);
       // Similar for eventVenue, venueCapacity, eventDate, and on

       JButton create = new JButton("Create an Event");
       wv.add(create, 10, 320, 300, 20);
       create.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                new Event();
                String eventName = name.getText();
                String eventVenue = venue.getText();
                int venueCapacity = Integer.parseInt(capacity);
                String eventDate = date.getText();
                int ticketsSold = Integer.parseInt(sold);
                int ticketPrice = Integer.parseInt(price);
                int overhead = Integer.parseInt(costs);
                
                
            }
        });    
    }
}
```

I have a class called Event in another Java file. In this `ActionListener`, I am hoping to create the object and have the inputs saved.
I can't parse the String inputs into integers and I have the error "The method parseInt() in the type integer is not applicable for the arguments (JTextField)" for those with Integer.parseInt();

Comment: based on how you're working with the other fields I'd guess it'll have to be `Integer.parseInt(capacity.getText())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be parsing the text of the `JTextField`s.

```
int venueCapacity = Integer.parseInt(capacity.getText());
String eventDate = date.getText();
int ticketsSold = Integer.parseInt(sold.getText());
int ticketPrice = Integer.parseInt(price.getText());
int overhead = Integer.parseInt(costs.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

From the exception you got, I think you should convert these vars to string first. For example

```
int capacitystr = capacity.getText();
```

And then you can convert them

```
int venueCapacity = Integer.parseInt(capacitystr);
```